# Javascript array not accessible outside of loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, scope

I have a JSON object containing IDs of data stored in a MySQL database. I am looping through the JSON object and sending the IDs via ajax to the database to return the data associated with that ID.

In that loop, after the data is returned, I am attempting to save that data to an array using:

```
finalArray.push({
    'nodeID' : nodeID,
    'startTime' : sDisplayTime,
    'endTime' : eDisplayTime
});
```

The data gets put into the array and I can use `console.log(finalArray);` while in the loop to see it put out the correct data. My problem is I cannot access the entire array outside of the loop. There should be 3-5 keys in the array when the loop is finished and the final output should include everything returned. When I call `console.log(finalArray);` outside of the loop I get a blank `[]` in the console.

I am declaring the `finalArray = [];` array outside/before the loop even starts so I wouldn't think the scope is an issue.

When I do it like `finalArray = { event: [ ] }` and then populate the data like:

```
finalArray.event.push({
    'nodeID': nodeID,
    'startTime': sDisplayTime,
    'endTime': eDisplayTime
});
```

I can `console.log(finalArray);` outside the loop and see the data. Unfortunately, I need this in a format I can use the `sort()` function on so this way won't work.

Would anyone happen to know why I can't access the array outside of the loop with the first method?

Here is the loop (simplified for display):

```
finalArray = [];

jQuery.each(cookieVal, function(i, v) {
    var nodeID = i;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: "action=get_scheduled_info&nid=" + nodeID,
        success: function(data) {

            var eventData = JSON.parse(data);
            var sDisplayTime = eventData.start_time;
            var eDisplayTime = eventData.end_time;

            finalArray.push({
                'nodeID': nodeID,
                'startTime': sDisplayTime,
                'endTime': eDisplayTime
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show the loop and such? My guess is you are making an asynchronous call.

Comment: Yes, give me a minute to simplify it for display.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't be making an AJAX call in an iteration - instead you could iterate through your cookieVal and make an array of nodeID's to send to the server side script and return an array.

For example:

```
var finalArray = [];
var sendArray  = [];

jQuery.each(cookieVal, function(i, v) {
    sendArray.push(i);
});

jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {action: "get_scheduled_info", data: sendArray},
        success: function(data) {

            var eventData = JSON.parse(data);
            var sDisplayTime = eventData.start_time;
            var eDisplayTime = eventData.end_time;

            // Loop round each item and add it to finalArray
        }
    });
```

This will save a lot of requests and allow you to handle the response properly.

The above code is just an example so it is untested.

Let me know if you have any questions.